# RegEx for URI Templates (RFC 6570) wanted

Tags: javascript, regex, jsonschema, uritemplate

I need to validate a string to ensure that it is a valid [URI Template according to RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). This *should* be quite easy with a regular expression. However, I did not find one – is there really no RegEx for URI Templates (yet)?

Context: I would like to use it in a JSON Schema that is processed with node.js.

Comment: I think a regex pattern thats validates URLs will work for you.

Comment: No it doesn't, since URLs don't allow the URI Template placeholders (like curly braces)

Comment: Well, can't you tweak the URL pattern?

Comment: Sure, I just wonder if there already is a battle-proven Regex out there…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late to the party here, but since the only answer doesn't address the issue of a regular expression for URI templates, I decided to take a stab at it as I couldn't find one either. This is based solely on the ABNF rules in [Section 2 of RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-2) and I included some ASCII art to map out the different components.

```
^([^\x00-\x20\x7f"'%<>\\^`{|}]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|{[+#./;?&=,!@|]?((\w|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(\.?(\w|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))*(:[1-9]\d{0,3}|\*)?)(,((\w|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(\.?(\w|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))*(:[1-9]\d{0,3}|\*)?))*})*$
  \                            \_____________/ \\____________/ \\__________________/    \__________________/ /\________________/ /  \_________________________________________________________________/ //
   \                            pct-encoded /   \   operator    \\     varchar                varchar       /  modifier-level4  /                               varspec                                //
    \______________________________________/     \               \\________________________________________/                   /                                                                      //
                    literals                      \               \                varname                                    /                                                                      //
                                                   \               \_________________________________________________________/                                                                      //
                                                    \               \                        varspec                                                                                               //
                                                     \               \____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//
                                                      \                                                                   variable-list                                                           /
                                                       \_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________/
                                                                                                                   expression
```

You can check it out on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DstcXC/1/). This should work in JSON Schema since I'm using the ECMA syntax. There might also be some simplifications that can be made, but as I said, this aligns with the ABNF, so it should be *relatively* easy to follow, if you're familiar with the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find what you want with this [library](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) which implements the RFC-6570 in Java.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
    <artifactId>uri-template</artifactId>
    <version>yourVersionHere</version>
</dependency>
```

The `URITemplate` constructor will return an `URITemplateParseException` if there is an error during the parsing.

```
final URITemplate template = new URITemplate("http://foo.bar/myPage{?map*}");
```